# Remove cancelling rows from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of invoices sent out to customers. However, sometimes a bad invoice is sent, which is later cancelled. My Pandas Dataframe looks something like this, except much larger (~3 million rows)

```
index | customer | invoice_nr | amount | date
---------------------------------------------------
0     | 1        | 1          | 10     | 01-01-2016
1     | 1        | 1          | -10    | 01-01-2016
2     | 1        | 1          | 11     | 01-01-2016
3     | 1        | 2          | 10     | 02-01-2016
4     | 2        | 3          | 7      | 01-01-2016
5     | 2        | 4          | 12     | 02-01-2016
6     | 2        | 4          | 8      | 02-01-2016
7     | 2        | 4          | -12    | 02-01-2016
8     | 2        | 4          | 4      | 02-01-2016
...   | ...      | ...        | ...    | ...
...   | ...      | ...        | ...    | ...
```

Now, I want to drop all rows for which the `customer`, `invoice_nr` and `date` are identical, but the `amount` has opposite values.
Corrections of invoices always take place on the same day with identical invoice number. The invoice number is uniquely bound to the customer and always corresponds to one transaction (which can consist of multiple components, for example for `customer = 2`, `invoice_nr = 4`). Corrections of invoices only occur either to change `amount` charged, or to split `amount` in smaller components. Hence, the cancelled value is not repeated on the same `invoice_nr`.

Any help how to program this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to read the rows in a `dict` where `invoice_nr` and `date` are separated by any delimiter say `#`. Now if you get any redundant key, delete it.

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma I'm not quite sure I follow what you mean. Should I read the `invoice_nr` and `date` as the `dict` keys? How would I then handle multiple rows with the same `invoice_nr` and `date`?

Comment: Since you want to drop all the rows with same `invoice_nr` and `date`, preparing the key string as `invoice_nr#date` would help you identify duplicate rows which you want to drop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't want to drop all rows with identical `invoice_nr` and `date`, but only those with opposite `amount` values. I don't want to drop row 3 from the dataframe for example.

Comment: Is possible in row with `index=3` in column `amount` is value `10` in real data?

Comment: This is a nice question but I think you should make it clearer. Do those always have the same date? Same invoice number? Can the same invoice number be assigned for the same customer, for something else?

Comment: Does it help if you start from the observation that any cancellation needs to involve a negative amount?  Those should not be too common in invoices, rebates aside perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def remove_cancelled_transactions(df):
    trans_neg = df.amount < 0
    return df.loc[~(trans_neg | trans_neg.shift(-1))]

groups = [df.customer, df.invoice_nr, df.date, df.amount.abs()]
df.groupby(groups, as_index=False, group_keys=False) \
  .apply(remove_cancelled_transactions)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is more complicated, because you need remove opposite values of amount. And it is very hard...

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm, I think your solution is better, because more general. My solution is faster, but some values cannot be find.

Comment: Thx @jezrael.  This was an interesting problem.  I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared! I'm glad you like the problem. Your solution is pretty awesome. Unfortunately, the `groupby` takes a long time over my 3 million rows. This definitely works for smaller datasets though and does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) all values, where each group has values where sum is `0` and modulo by `2` is `0`:

```
print (df.groupby([df.customer, df.invoice_nr, df.date, df.amount.abs()])
        .filter(lambda x: (len(x.amount.abs()) % 2 == 0 ) and (x.amount.sum() == 0)))

       customer  invoice_nr  amount        date
index                                          
0             1           1      10  01-01-2016
1             1           1     -10  01-01-2016
5             2           4      12  02-01-2016
6             2           4     -12  02-01-2016

idx = df.groupby([df.customer, df.invoice_nr, df.date, df.amount.abs()])
        .filter(lambda x: (len(x.amount.abs()) % 2 == 0 ) and (x.amount.sum() == 0)).index

print (idx)      
Int64Index([0, 1, 5, 6], dtype='int64', name='index')

print (df.drop(idx))  
       customer  invoice_nr  amount        date
index                                          
2             1           1      11  01-01-2016
3             1           2      10  02-01-2016
4             2           3       7  01-01-2016
7             2           4       8  02-01-2016
8             2           4       4  02-01-2016
```

EDIT by comment:

If in real data are not duplicates for one invoice and one customer and one date, so you can use this way:

```
 print (df)
   index  customer  invoice_nr  amount        date
0      0         1           1      10  01-01-2016
1      1         1           1     -10  01-01-2016
2      2         1           1      11  01-01-2016
3      3         1           2      10  02-01-2016
4      4         2           3       7  01-01-2016
5      5         2           4      12  02-01-2016
6      6         2           4     -12  02-01-2016
7      7         2           4       8  02-01-2016
8      8         2           4       4  02-01-2016

df['amount_abs'] = df.amount.abs()
df.drop_duplicates(['customer','invoice_nr', 'date', 'amount_abs'], keep=False, inplace=True)
df.drop('amount_abs', axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
   index  customer  invoice_nr  amount        date
2      2         1           1      11  01-01-2016
3      3         1           2      10  02-01-2016
4      4         2           3       7  01-01-2016
7      7         2           4       8  02-01-2016
8      8         2           4       4  02-01-2016
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out, @jezrael! Similar to @piRSquared's solution, yours works great for the small dataset. Unfortunately, for my 3 million row dataframe, the operation takes a rather long time.

Comment: Yes, your task is very complicated. So if need something faster, it is problematic. But one question - how often in 3M rows are cancelled invoices (estimated)?

Comment: You can get `df1` with all duplicates: `df['amount_abs'] = df.amount.abs()`
    `df1 = df[df.duplicated(['customer','invoice_nr', 'date', 'amount_abs'], keep=False)]`
    `print (df1)` What is size of `df1`? `len(df1)`

Comment: `len(df1)` is about 30,000 items shorter. But this seems like a perfect solution to me! This drops the rows where the absolute values have become identical, so cancelled each other before. If you post this in a separate reply, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm, i think it is solution only for testing, because if you have duplicity more as 2 times, you lost your good data - see sample `df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, 'invoice_nr': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}, 'customer': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2}, 'amount': {0: 10, 1: -10, 2: 10, 3: 11, 4: 7}, 'date': {0: '01-01-2016', 1: '01-01-2016', 2: '01-01-2016', 3: '02-01-2016', 4: '01-01-2016'}})` and value `10`. So this situtation is possible in real data?

Comment: And there is another problem - what if you have four times `10` value in one invoice for one customer? Then you lost all 4 rows with good data.

Comment: No, this doesn't happen in the real data, because revoking the invoice would not be necessary then. I'll specify this in my original question for clarity, such that the accepted answer makes sense.

Comment: Concerning your second comment, that might be a valid remark. The invoice could get split fifty-fifty in smaller amounts, which would get lost. That's a pity.

Comment: Yes, and so solution is complicated. :(

Comment: So i think you can use `piRSquared` solution, which is better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What if you just do a groupby on all 3 fields?  The resulting sums would net out any canceled invoices:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['customer','invoice_nr','date']).sum()
```

results in

```
customer invoice_nr date
1        1          2016/01/01      11
         2          2016/02/01      10
2        3          2016/01/01       7
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution. However, I see now, my example data is not complete enough, because my invoices occasionally get split in smaller amounts, which I want to consider separately. I've updated my original question accordingly.