# drop rows based on specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a part of df:

```
   NUMBER         MONEY
    12345           20
    12345          -20
    12345           20
    12345           20
    123456          10
    678910          7.6
    123457          3
    678910         -7.6
```

I want to drop rows which have the same NUMBER but opposite money.

The ideal outcome would like below:

```
    NUMBER         MONEY
    12345           20
    12345           20
    123456          10  
    123457          3
```

note: these entries are not one-to-one correspondence (I mean the total amount is an odd number).

For example, there are four entries are [Number] 12345.

three of them [Money] are 20, one [Money] is -20.

I just want to delete two [Money] is the opposite, and keep the other two whose money is 20.

Comment: Hello, so basically, you want to remove the negative values right?

Comment: I want to remove the entries which contain the negative number and also their corresponding entries whose number is opposite.

Comment: [Possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831088/remove-cancelling-rows-from-pandas-dataframe)?

Comment: is each `NUMBER` has only one single value repeating with different sign or each may have multiple different values? For example: `NUMBER 12345` may also have value `40` besides `20 and -20` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using `groupby` and `apply` and a custom function to match and delete pairs.

```
def remove_pairs(x):
    positive = x.loc[x['MONEY'] > 0].index.values
    negative = x.loc[x['MONEY'] < 0].index.values
    for i, j in zip(positive, negative):
        x = x.drop([i, j])
    return x

df['absvalues'] = df['MONEY'].abs()

dd = df.groupby(['NUMBER', 'absvalues']).apply(remove_pairs)
dd.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dd.drop('absvalues', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

`'absvalue'` column with the absolute values of `'MONEY'` is added to perform a double index selection with `groupby`, and then the custom function drops rows in pairs selecting positive and negative numbers.

The two last lines just do some cleaning. Using your sample dataframe, the final result `dd` is:

```
   NUMBER  MONEY
0   12345   20.0
1   12345   20.0
2  123456   10.0
3  123457    3.0
```